# Dealing with spaces in filenames in a batch loop

Tags: loops, batch-file

I trying to write a batch file that recursively goes through the directories (taking into account spaces as well) and performs an ImageMagick command. I have the following:

```
for /R %%a IN (*.png) do mogrify %%a -fuzz 0% -transparent none
```

Note: this gets stuck with spaces.

I also tried this:

```
for /R "tokens=*" %%a IN (*.png) do mogrify %%a -fuzz 0% -transparent none
```

Note: this version doesn't spit an error, but does not modify the contents of the folder.

Any help is appreciated. 
Kind regards, 
Alex

Comment: Mistype^^^ for /R "tokens=*" %%a IN (.png) do mogrify %%a -fuzz 0% -transparent none

Comment: Similar - but I am trying not to specify the directories. I am also using the ImageMagic commands.

Comment: The information is there in those answers. Read them, and see how they apply to your own code. The second one, for instance, uses an `echo` in the `for` loop to output the file name from a `dir` listing; that example applies **directly** to your question here.

Comment: Seriously consider using Powershell for this. It will not have the same problems with spaces, and its looping constructs are much simpler: `Get-ChildItem *.png | ForEach-Object { mogrify $_ -fuzz 0% -transparent none }` or even shorter: `ls *.png | % { mogrify $_ fuzz 0% -transparent none }`

Answer (score 1):

```
for /R %%a IN (*.png) do mogrify "%%~fa" -fuzz 0%% -transparent none
```

Please note the double percent signs in `0%%`.